# Does the use of 就 and 便 vary by region?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms, topolect

就 and 便 are synonymous in many sentences:

> 这儿（就、便）是我们的学校。
>   我看了报纸（就、便）扔了。
>   如果你去，我（就、便）不去了。

I believe that 便 is more formal than 就; I've seen it in writing but never heard it in speech. However, my Chinese experience is mostly limited to the south, and 
perhaps it's common in other regions.

Is 便 a common subsitute for 就 in certain parts of China? In places where 便 is common, can it be used everywhere that 就 is used? Are there sentences where 就 is appropriate but 便 is not?

Comment: Where did you see it written?

Comment: @trideceth12 I don't have citations at hand, but it's pretty common in Chinese short stories and novels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a native speaker, I certainly never encounter anyone from any part of the mainland who uses "便" in colloquial language frequently, if ever. I'd say "便" is basically a written equivalent of "就".

Answer (score 2):

"就“ and "便" almost has the same meaning. But it's a lot common to use "就" in speaking. And it's not a region issue.

Comment: Hello Magic and welcome to Chinese Language and Usage! :D Your answer is a bit short, do you mind expanding a bit? It's ok and actually it would improve its quality if you explained in what cases 就 or 便 are used and why and also about that region issue. :)